# Getting a matrix for a Maze; Python

Tags: python-3.x, path-finding, maze

I have created a successful path finding algorithm  on Python. It works on any sized matrices like this:

```
maze=[[' ',' ','X','X',' ','S'],
      [' ',' ',' ',' ','X',' '],
      ['F','X',' ',' ',' ',' '],
      [' ',' ',' ',' ','X',' '],
      [' ','X',' ',' ',' ',' ']]
```

The S is the starting point, the X marks walls and the F is the finish point.

Where can I get a maze in the same format as this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a text file named as input.txt and read from that test file in list.

input.txt

```
  XX S
    X 
FX    
    X 
 X
```

read from file into list like this:

```
with open('C:/input.txt') as f:
    maze = f.read().splitlines()
```

where maze is your list. It will be same as you shown above.

And then for verification you can print like this (which shows you the contents of input.txt):

```
for sublist in maze:
    print(''.join(sublist))
```